# Probability current: How does one write it only in terms of Imaginary terms?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics

[image: I guess I am lacking the mathematical basis to it.]

How and why do we write the probability current in terms of imaginary part? What are the mathematical steps in between the steps ?

Comment: Please use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) when the picture only contains an equation, this would avoid broken pictures in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a complex number given by $z=a+ i b$, where $a,b\in $Reals. You can work out that $z-\bar{z}=2ib$, where $z^*=a-ib$ is the complex conjugate of $z$. Note that $b=\operatorname{Im}(z)$.